# How do I trim leading and trailing whitespace from input fields in web2py?

Tags: web2py, trim, removing-whitespace

As the title says, how do I trim leading and trailing whitespace from input fields in web2py?  I've tried the [CLEANUP()](http://web2py.com/examples/static/epydoc/web2py.gluon.validators.CLEANUP-class.html) validator which works but unfortunately it strips out other special characters which I do not want stripped out (for example, ¥).

Also what are the characters it's stripping out?  This is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CLEANUP` takes a `regex` argument, which defaults to `'[^\x09\x0a\x0d\x20-\x7e]'`. It first strips leading and trailing whitespace and then removes any characters that match the regex. Since you only need to remove the whitespace, you can supply an empty regex:

```
Field('myfield', requires=CLEANUP(''))
```

You could also achieve the same with a custom validator:

```
Field('myfield', requires=lambda v: (str(v).strip(), None))
```

Comment: Interesting I wasn't aware of the lambda form of validators. Is this documented?  Also what does the `f` argument represent?

Comment: A validator is just a callable object that takes a field object and a value and returns a tuple, with the first item being the value (possibly transformed) and the second either an error message or `None`. You can make a custom validator using a class with a `__call__` method (which is how all of the built-in validators work) or just with a function or lambda. The reason the field object is passed in is so the validator can make use of any relevant field attributes.

Comment: The example of a custom validator in the book doesn't seem to take a field object http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/07#Custom-validators is there a mistake?

Comment: My mistake. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I ended up creating a custom validator as that communicated the intent better and I knew exactly what it was doing.  Also CLEANUP I think strips out non-Latin characters which may not be good for multilingual site.

Comment: The above version of CLEANUP shouldn't remove any characters. It just applies .strip to remove leading and trailing spaces.